# can dynamically load classes be rebind to static reference?

Tags: java

[Reference: dynamic load java code](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071777/design-patterns/add-dynamic-java-code-to-your-application.html?page=1)

```
public interface Postman {
    void deliverMessage(String msg);
}

//loaded by dynamic class loader, with parent class loader pointing to main
public class PostmanImpl implements Postman {
}

public class PostmanApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Postman postman = getPostman();
        while (true) {
            //postman.deliverMessage(msg);
            getPostman().deliverMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    private static Postman getPostman() {
        // Omit for now, will come back later
        // ???
    }
 }
```

> How do you access the up-to-date dynamic class with a static reference? Apparently, a direct (normal) reference to a dynamic class's object will not do the trick.

I don't quite follow the above statement. not `apparent` to me. The dynamic class loader will always reference `main` class loader as parent class loader , thus the `Postman` interface is always valid, the dynamic class loader always load a new `Impl` class which is compatible with the `interface`.

```
InvocationHandler handler = new DynaCodeInvocationHandler(...);
    Postman proxy = (Postman) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Postman.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { Postman.class },
                handler);
```

The author eventually suggested using a Proxy to delegate calls on interface to newly loaded implementation.

> Apparently, a direct (normal) reference to a dynamic class's object will not do the trick.

what's the problem with direct reference assignment of newly loaded class? why eventually a `Proxy` is needed?

Comment: *"what the obvious problem here?"* What *is* the problem here? It's not clear from your question. *"why eventually a `Proxy` is needed?"* It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already fixed the code so that it's not necessary.

The original code does this (simplified):

```
Postman p = getPostman();
while(true) {
    p.deliverMessage();
}
```

There's no way for the code in `Postman` to change the object `p` refers to. When it loads the updated class and creates a new instance of the new class, `p` still refers to the old instance of the old class.

But if you do this instead:

```
while(true) {
    getPostman().deliverMessage();
}
```

then `getPostman` will return an instance of the new class once it's loaded, and there is no problem.

Comment: weird, so it's just a matter of switching between old reference and new reference and keeping track of that. what's the point of that complicated complexity. maybe that's more convenient and efficient? @dasblinkenlight would you agree this ?

Comment: @zinking There's still a problem, because you cannot pass `getPostman` to a method or constructor that takes `Postman`, only a result of the call to `getPostman()`. If the method or constructor decides to store `Postman`, you are back to the same problem of stale references. Therefore, all users down the road must stick to the same `getPostman().doSomething()` pattern. This adds a lot more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesnt allow to change an instances type at runtime. The dynamic loaded class is always a new class incompatible with the old one even if structurally equivalent or even same bytecode (they might share a common superclass or interface).

So if you hand out the plain instances to the clients, there is no way of "recalling" them. You can only invalide the instances and force the client to get a fresh instance.

A Proxy allows you to change the delegate you redirect the calls to. So you hand out the Proxy to your client. When you load a new version of the class you can change a property of the proxy. All clients can continue working on their proxy reference.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing making the class dynamic is our ability to redirect a reference to the dynamic class as we wish.

We cannot do it without a proxy:

[image: No proxy]

the link shown in red represents a reference from a Java variable to the object. We do not own the variable, and we do not know how it is used. The client can pass variable as a parameter, or assign it to a field, making multiple copies of the red link, making it impossible to manage it.

Proxy adds another level of indirection:

[image: With a proxy]

We still don't own the red link. However, the green link is inside the proxy, so it is fully under our control. If we decide to redirect it to a different object, and we have multiple clients referencing it, all client objects will redirect after a single reassignment.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit, to me, the reference assignment is just like `pointer` assignment. the loading/link process have no problem, which part of JVM is preventing this?

Comment: @zinking Changing a reference is indeed like a pointer assignment. The problem is, we don't know where the references are. For example, when the client does `Postman p = getPostman()` and we return something, we have no way of re-assigning `p`. In addition, the client can do `Postman anotherP = p`, which is completely outside our code. We don't even know that `copyP` exists! If we return a proxy, on the other hand, all we need to do is keeping a reference to our proxy: now the link to dynamic class is ours to reassign at will.